# Martingale based on normal PDF evaluated at normalized i.i.d. sums

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, martingales

I have the following problem.

- $(X_n)_{n\geq0}, n\in\mathrm{R}$, is a family of iid r.v., normally distributed $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$
- $\mathcal{F_n} := \sigma((X_i)_{1\leq i\leq n})$
- $x\in\mathrm{R}, \phi(x)$ is the repartition function of a the normal distribution ($\phi(x):=\mathrm{P}[X_1\leq x]$)

if $b$ is fixed and $\in \mathrm{R}$, show that $(M_k)_{0\leq k < n}$, where

- $M_k = \phi\left(\frac{b-S_k}{\sqrt{n-k}}\right)$, $\forall k \in \left\{ {1,..,n-1}\right\} $, $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k} X_i$, $S_0=0$

is a martingale.

Please help me

Comment: The definition of $M_n$ seems to involve dividing by zero.

Comment: I was thinking the same...maybe there is a mistake in the statement of the exercise.
if $k < n$, would my attempt be correct?

Comment: Obviously $(M_k)$ is adapted to the filtration generated by $(S_k)$, which coincides with the filtration generated by $(X_k)$... For the exercise itself, see my answer (which assumes you will be able to reach a correct exercise statement).

Comment: About integrability: this is a non-issue since the function $\phi$ is bounded.

Comment: Why did you erase your tries? They are the reason why the question follows the rules of the site...

Comment: Any success in reaching a plausible proposition?

Comment: sorry, I noticed I made a (very stupid) mistake in my attempt...$\phi(\frac{b-S_k}{\sqrt{n-k}})$ is $\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{b-S_k}{\sqrt{n-k}}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$ and not $\int_{R} f(\frac{b-S_k}{\sqrt{n-k}})$

Comment: ...Attempt which you suppressed from the question--so why should we care? But this was not my question: *Any success in reaching a plausible proposition?*

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: I took $u=\frac{-1}{\sqrt(n-k-1)}$, $v=\frac{b-S_k}{\sqrt(n-k-1)}$, after all the computations I got $E[M_{k+1}]=\frac{1}{\sqrt\frac{n-k}{n-k-1}} \phi(\frac{b-S_k}{\sqrt(n-k)})$.

Answer (score 2):

**Factlet:** For every $(u,v)$, if $X$ is standard normal, then $$E(\phi(uX+v))=\int_\mathbb R \phi(ux+v)\phi(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$ Simple algebraic manipulations show that $$\phi(ux+v)\phi(x)=\phi(uvw+w^{-1}x)\phi(vw),\qquad \color{red}{w=(u^2+1)^{-1/2}},$$ hence, using the change of variable $z=uvw+w^{-1}x$, one gets the key-identity $$E(\phi(uX+v))=\phi(vw)\int_\mathbb R \phi(uvw+w^{-1}x)\,\mathrm dx=\phi(vw)\int_\mathbb R \phi(z)\,(w\,\mathrm dz),$$ that is, $$\color{red}{E(\phi(uX+v))=w\cdot\phi(vw).}$$

---

**Application:** If $M_{k+1}=C_k\phi(u_kX_{k+1}+Y_k)$ for some constants $C_k$ and $u_k$ and some random variable $Y_k$ $\mathcal F_k$-measurable then $$E(M_{k+1}\mid\mathcal F_k)=C_kw_k\cdot\phi(w_kY_k).$$ where, naturally, $w_k=(u_k^2+1)^{-1/2}$. Identifying $u_k$, $C_k$ and $Y_k$ should show (once the text of the exercise is corrected) that the RHS is $M_k$.